# MATLAB : draw a line till the target point

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-deployment

I am testing a code to make a function so that first it draws a point on the given coordinates but when I click it draws a line from [0,0,0] till that given coordinates

```
x = 10
y = 20
z=30
plot3(x,y,z,'ok')
hold on
w = waitforbuttonpress;
if (w == 0)
    plot3(x,y,z,'--.b')
end
```

so far the the code works like this 
first it plots the following function 
[image]

and then when I click it just plots a dot with in the circle [image]
I have also tried making a matrix from plot3(0:x,0:y,0:z,'--.b') but as I would not be knowing the actual coordinates(would be reading it from a file) so the vector size would not be equal for x , y , and z , what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
x = 10
y = 20
z = 30
plot3(x,y,z,'og')
axis([0 100 0 100 0 100])
hold on
w = waitforbuttonpress;
if (w == 0)
    plot3(linspace(0,x,100),linspace(0,y,100),linspace(0,z,100),'--b')
end
```

solves my problem thanks anyways